# How to get next id for img

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, carousel

When I hover `li` with number `3` I get wrong number for `next id` in `img`. On first hover I get `next id` = 4, that's wrong. On second hover I get `next id` = 0 that's what I need.
How to make correctly `next id` on hover like a carousel

```js
let chosen_li = [];
let next_id;

$(".navigate li").on("mouseover", function () {
  let li = $(this);

  let index_li = li.index();

  chosen_li.unshift(index_li);
  if (chosen_li.length > 2) {
    chosen_li.pop();
  }
  if (chosen_li[0] !== chosen_li[1]) {
    $("#slider #img_" + chosen_li[0])
      .prependTo("#slider")
  }
  /////how to get next id?
  next_id =
    next_id > $(".navigate li").length - 1
      ? 0
      : parseInt($("#slider").children().attr("id").split("_")[1], 10) + 1;

  console.log(next_id);
  $("#slider #img_" + next_id).insertAfter($("#slider img:first"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider">
    <img id="img_0" src="1.jpg" style="margin-left:10px">
    <img id="img_1" src="2.jpg" style="margin-left:20px">
    <img id="img_2" src="3.jpg" style="margin-left:30px">
    <img id="img_3" src="4.jpg" style="margin-left:40px">
</div>

<ul class="navigate">
    <li>0</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: why not simply count the images and use modulo? https://playcode.io/709185/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to get value of nextid from current element before comparison

```
next_id = parseInt($("#slider").children().attr("id").split("_")[1], 10) + 1; 

if (next_id > ($(".navigate li").length - 1) )
  next_id = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

@crack_iT is right you just need to initialize the value.  I would set it like this...

```
let chosen_li = [];
let next_id;

$(".navigate li").on("mouseover", function () {
  let li = $(this);

  let index_li = li.index();
  

  chosen_li.unshift(index_li);
  if (chosen_li.length > 2) {
    chosen_li.pop();
  }
  if (chosen_li[0] !== chosen_li[1]) {
    $("#slider #img_" + chosen_li[0])
      .prependTo("#slider")
  }
  /////how to get next id?
  next_id = index_li +1;
  next_id =
    next_id > $(".navigate li").length - 1
      ? 0
      : parseInt($("#slider").children().attr("id").split("_")[1], 10) + 1;

  console.log(next_id);
  $("#slider #img_" + next_id).insertAfter($("#slider img:first"));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Lot of solutions, this for example:

```
  $(".navigate li").on("mouseover", function () {

    var id = parseInt($(this).text());
    var nextid = $(".navigate li").eq(id + 1).length ? id + 1 : 0;

  });
```

if you want to trap the number of id of img :

```
    var nextid = $("#slider").find("img").eq(id + 1).attr('id').replace(/\D/g,"");
```

`replace(/\D/g,"")`  keeps only number

after you could use modulo function % if your number is following...

so   `nextid = (id + 1) % $(".navigate li").length;`

so 4 modulo 4 = 0

Answer (score 1):

first of all you should initialize the li elements adding a new custom attribute with then next index like this:

```
function linkItems(selector) {
    const items = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    items.forEach((node, index) => {
      node.setAttribute('data-next', (index +1));
    });
    items[items.length - 1].setAttribute('data-next', 0);
}
linkItems('ul.navigate li');
```

After linking the nodes, you can read directly using li.attr('data-next')